# Unable to access response headers with response.headers in a createAsyncThunk Fetch Request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, fetch-api, redux-toolkit

This is my fetch request in `playerSlice.js`:

```
export const fetchPlayer = createAsyncThunk(
  "players/fetchPlayer",
  async (payload) => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "AgentId": `${localStorage.agentId}` ? `${localStorage.agentId}` : null
      },
    };
    // console.log(options)
    const response = await fetch(
      `URL HERE`,
      options
    );

    if (response.ok) {
      console.log(response.headers)
      const player = await response.json();
      console.log(player)
      return { ...player };
    }
  }
);
```

The `console.log(player)` works as expected, i.e., I am in fact getting the response, but when I check `response.headers` it's an empty object even though I've allowed and exposed headers on the server???

[image: headers object]

CORS setup on node/express side is as follows:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    "origin": "http://localhost:3001",
    "methods": ["GET", "PUT", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
    "allowedHeaders": ["Content-Type", "AgentId", "Accept"],
    "exposedHeaders": ["Content-Type", "AgentId", "Accept"],
    "credentials": true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', public)
```

And I'm setting the custom header server side:

```
res.header('AgentId', agentId)
res.status(200).send({...REMOVED FOR BREVITY});
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

P.S. This is my first project using `redux/toolkit`

Comment: That makes ZERO sense. The problem is still reproducible and wasn't caused by a "typo". At face value, it makes sense to be checking for headers as a plain object that should be retrievable with ```response.headers```. People, especially beginners, can potentially get stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I am just an idiot. This is a viewing issue in the console, from what I can gather `fetch` doesn't return a plain object for `Headers` and I have to retrieve them like `response.headers.get('AgentId')` or iterate over them.